# how to clone an object in android?

Tags: java, android

What would be the best way to copy/clone an object in java/android?

```
rlBodyDataObj rlbo = bdoTable.get(name);
```

Right now the code assigns an object from a hashTable, yet I need to get a clone of it, so that I'd be able to use it multiple times.

Comment: Check out this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869033/how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-java

Comment: that's my custom object, it doesn't have .clone()

Comment: @RogerTravis All objects in Java have the `clone()` method which they inherit from the `Object` superclass. You may need to override this to make it useful in your custom class.

Comment: You don't need to clone it to be able to use it multiple times. I've never used `clone()` in production code in twenty years.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Make sure that your DataObj class implements Cloneable and add the following method

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
}
```

Then you should be able to call (DataObj)rlBodyDataObj.clone(); to get a clean copy (note the cast).

Comment: hmm... not really, please see this question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636673/android-cloned-object-also-clones-new-data-how-to-prevent-that

Comment: You don't need to add the method.

Comment: Make your implementation of clone public, so that you can use anywhere.

Answer (score 11):

```
class Test implements Cloneable
  {
   ...
      public Object clone()
      {
          try
      {
              return super.clone();
          }
      catch( CloneNotSupportedException e )
      {
              return null;
          }
      } 
  ...
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

you can implements Parcelable (easy with studio plugin), and then

```
public static <T extends Parcelable> T copy(T orig) {
    Parcel p = Parcel.obtain();
    orig.writeToParcel(p, 0);
    p.setDataPosition(0);
    T copy = null;
    try {
        copy = (T) orig.getClass().getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[]{Parcel.class}).newInstance(p);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return copy;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you need to modify some fields before returning from the clone() method.

Check this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone().
I pasted the relevant part here for convenience:

> "By convention, the object returned by this method should be
>   independent of this object (which is being cloned). To achieve this
>   independence, it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the
>   object returned by super.clone before returning it. Typically, this
>   means copying any mutable objects that comprise the internal "deep
>   structure" of the object being cloned and replacing the references to
>   these objects with references to the copies. If a class contains only
>   primitive fields or references to immutable objects, then it is
>   usually the case that no fields in the object returned by super.clone
>   need to be modified."

Comment: thanks. please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636673/android-cloned-object-also-clones-new-data-how-to-prevent-that , seems it clones integrated objects that were assigned AFTER the .clone() took place...

Answer (score 1):

i wish to implement with :
**copy constructor**

```
class DataObj {
  private String tag;

  public DataObj(DataObj another) {
    this.tag= another.tag; // you can access  
    ...
  }
}
```

Every object has also a clone method which can be used to copy the object, but It's way too easy to create a class and do improper clone method. If you are going to do with implement clone method, read at least what Joshua Bloch has to say about it in *[Effective Java](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA55&lpg=PA55&dq=effective+java+clone&source=bl&ots=yXGhLnv4O4&sig=zvEip5tp5KGgwqO1sCWgtGyJ1Ns&hl=en&ei=CYANSqygK8jktgfM-JGcCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#PPA54,M1)*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify on your class that it implements [Cloneable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html) interface and you have to override `clone` method inside that class. By Default it will use `clone` method of `Object` class.