# Cloned object also clones new data, how to prevent that?

Tags: java

EDIT:

**Thanks guys, got it! appears that the explode() function was called from the old object, rather then it's new clone! :)**

---

I have a hashtable of such objects

```
class BodyDataObj implements Cloneable {

  World world;
  Body body;

  protected BodyDataObj clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return (BodyDataObj) super.clone();
  }

}
```

when needed, I make a clone of a needed object from the hashtable

```
BodyDataObj bodyDataMaster = bdoTable.get(name);
BodyDataObj bodyData = null;

try {
  bodyData = (BodyDataObj) bodyDataMaster.clone();
} catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) { 
  // Handle error
}

bodyData.world = world;
bodyData.body = body;
```

and pass the `world` and `body` objects to my already cloned `bodyData` object.

Yet when I try to access this world and body object from within the `BodyDataObj` object, I get a `NullPointException`, as if they are cloned blanks.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: In the following codes where does w and body come from? `rlbo.w = w;
        rlbo.b = body;`

Comment: I've edited the code above, w and body are working, when I assign them to the rlbo object. Yet, they give a nullpoint when accessed from withing the rlbo object, by calling the explode() function.

Comment: Why are you not putting all of the clone logic in the `clone()` method of `rlBodyDataObj` ?

Comment: didn't really understand about the clone logic, how should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answer to the comment the answer seems to be this:

b.getWorldCenter() returns null.

Comment: yes, I know that. :) the problem is why does it return a null.

Comment: You should provide some more information about the Body class then.

Comment: putting it simple, I've got a an object called "body", which works fine before I pass it to my cloned "rlbo" object. Yet when I try to access it from withing the "rlbo" object, it gives my a null. I believe that's because when I pass it to the cloned rlbo object, it doesn't make a reference, but rather also makes some sort of a cone of the object. So the question is, how to make the rlbo object make references, rather then cloning newly passed objects.

Comment: The problem does not seem to be related with cloning, because you assign w and b fields separately. When you call the clone method, you get a regular Java object, nothing special. And then you assign w and b fields manually. So, there should be something else.

Comment: yet it is related to cloning. :) how else can I explain that w and b where working before being assigned and then turned into nulls afterwards. :)

Comment: Can you try the following: instead of calling the super.clone() method in the clone() method, just create a new instance and assign members by hand, creating new instance as needed. So what I mean is do the cloning manually. This might provide some clues on the issue.

Comment: yes, just did this manual cloning, but the problem is still there... :/

Comment: Can you post source code for Body? At least getWorldCenter() method and the parts related with that method.

Comment: I can't, as its a class from JBox2d engine. I guess the problem isn't in the Body itself, as it does work fine before being assigned... hmm...

Comment: So that means the problem is related with a completely different matter. Most probably you got a mistake somewhere you never suspect. You now we can do such silly mistakes sometimes. I recommend you to give a break and then see through your code with a fresh mind again. :)

Comment: simplifies it even more, see above, yet it still gives a null. :)))